# Renaming in ArcGIS Field calculator with python

Tags: field, calculator, renaming

Trying to do a simple rename in ArcGIS 9.2 - field calculator. Using !dsm_loc!.replace("H:\", "F:\") where dsm_loc is the field name. Keep getting a syntax error! Any thoughts??

Answer (score 0):

I see that no one answered this question, and the post is now almost a year old...

I don't see anything wrong with the syntax. The expression should work.

```
!dsm_loc!.replace("H:\", "F:\")
```

It worked for me in ArcGIS 10.2.2